# javax validation can't find Hibernate Validator in Karaf

Tags: maven, osgi, bean-validation, hibernate-validator, karaf

I've implemented some code using javax.validation and Hibernate Validator. The unit tests using validation are working fine. The build produces OSGi bundles and features, and runs in Karaf.

When I run my PaxExam integration test, I get "Unable to create a Configuration, because no Bean Validation provider could be found. Add a provider like Hibernate Validator (RI) to your classpath." As far as I can tell, I AM adding it to my classpath. I have a features.xml file that I've been incrementally adding dependencies to. It finally got past Karaf bundle resolution, but now it's failing with an exception with this message:

"Unable to create a Configuration, because no Bean Validation provider could be found. Add a provider like Hibernate Validator (RI) to your classpath."

I would include the stacktrace, but it doesn't look useful to me. Most of it is in my code, junit, and paxexam.

I'm attempting to use version 5.4.1.Final of HV. Note again that the unit tests doing validation are working fine. It took a while to get the dependencies correct to get that far (like using version "3.0.1-b08" of "javax.el".

I've seen some mentions of a "hibernate-validator-osgi-karaf-features" artifact, but I'm not sure if that's relevant. I'm attempting to use both the hibernate-validator artifact and the hibernate-validator-annotation-processor artifact.

I don't know that it's going to matter, but here's an excerpt of my POM dependencies:

```
        <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
        <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
        <version>5.4.1.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>
            hibernate-validator-annotation-processor
        </artifactId>
        <version>5.4.1.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.el</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.1-b08</version>
    </dependency>
```

The following is an excerpt of a "features.xml" file from a bundle that is a dependency (by feature) of the bundle containing the test class:

```
    <bundle start-level="100">wrap:mvn:javax.validation/validation-api/1.1.0.Final$Bundle-Name=javax.validation&amp;Bundle-SymbolicName=javax.validation&amp;Bundle-Version=1.1.0.Final</bundle>
    <bundle>mvn:org.hibernate/hibernate-validator/5.4.1.Final</bundle>
    <bundle start-level="100">wrap:mvn:org.hibernate/hibernate-validator-annotation-processor/5.4.1.Final$Bundle-Name=hibernate-validator-annotation-processor&amp;Bundle-SymbolicName=hibernate-validator-annotation-processor&amp;Bundle-Version=5.4.1.Final</bundle>
```

What else can I do at this point?

**Update**:

I've made some changes according to the answer that refers to the "hibernate-validator-osgi-karaf-features" artifact, but I'm now getting a different unexpected error.

In the pom dependencies I added the following:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>
            hibernate-validator-osgi-karaf-features
        </artifactId>
        <version>5.4.1.Final</version>
        <type>pom</type>
    </dependency>
```

In the base features.xml file that is referred to by the features.xml file in my module, I removed the annotation-processor, and added this:

```
    <bundle>wrap:mvn:org.hibernate/hibernate-validator-osgi-karaf-features/5.4.1.Final$Bundle-Name=hibernate-validator-osgi-karaf-features&amp;Bundle-SymbolicName=hibernate-validator-osgi-karaf-features&amp;Bundle-Version=5.4.1.Final</bundle>
```

I tried not having the "wrap:" and everything after the "$", but the result was the same.

When I ran my test, I saw this:

```
Caused by: shaded.org.eclipse.aether.transfer.ArtifactNotFoundException: Could not find artifact org.hibernate:hibernate-validator-osgi-karaf-features:jar:5.4.1.Final in central (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/)
at shaded.org.eclipse.aether.connector.basic.ArtifactTransportListener.transferFailed(ArtifactTransportListener.java:39)[7:org.ops4j.pax.url.mvn:2.4.7]
at shaded.org.eclipse.aether.connector.basic.BasicRepositoryConnector$TaskRunner.run(BasicRepositoryConnector.java:355)[7:org.ops4j.pax.url.mvn:2.4.7]
at shaded.org.eclipse.aether.util.concurrency.RunnableErrorForwarder$1.run(RunnableErrorForwarder.java:67)[7:org.ops4j.pax.url.mvn:2.4.7]
at shaded.org.eclipse.aether.connector.basic.BasicRepositoryConnector$DirectExecutor.execute(BasicRepositoryConnector.java:581)[7:org.ops4j.pax.url.mvn:2.4.7]
at shaded.org.eclipse.aether.connector.basic.BasicRepositoryConnector.get(BasicRepositoryConnector.java:249)[7:org.ops4j.pax.url.mvn:2.4.7]
at shaded.org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.performDownloads(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:520)[7:org.ops4j.pax.url.mvn:2.4.7]
at shaded.org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolve(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:421)[7:org.ops4j.pax.url.mvn:2.4.7]
... 16 more
```

It's curious that it says it can't find it in central.  I can verify the artifact is my local maven cache, because my build likely copied it there after I added the maven dependency as described above.

**Update**:

I'm guessing that part of my problem is that this artifact is a POM artifact, not a JAR artifact, but I don't understand how I need to reference it.

**Update**:

Someone on karaf-user pointed out that I need to reference it as a feature, not a bundle, so I now replaced my bundle references with the following:

```
<feature>hibernate-validator-osgi-karaf-features</feature>
```

Along with the following repository definition next to two other repository definitions:

```
    <repository>mvn:org.hibernate/hibernate-validator-osgi-karaf-features/5.4.1.Final/xml/features</repository>
```

However, after installing the features file and then rerunning my test, it fails with this:

```
org.osgi.service.resolver.ResolutionException: Unable to resolve root: missing requirement [root] osgi.identity; osgi.identity=usl-fraudcheck; type=karaf.feature; version="[2.5.0.SNAPSHOT,2.5.0.SNAPSHOT]"; filter:="(&(osgi.identity=usl-fraudcheck)(type=karaf.feature)(version>=2.5.0.SNAPSHOT)(version<=2.5.0.SNAPSHOT))" [caused by: Unable to resolve usl-fraudcheck/2.5.0.SNAPSHOT: missing requirement [usl-fraudcheck/2.5.0.SNAPSHOT] osgi.identity; osgi.identity=usl-base; type=karaf.feature [caused by: Unable to resolve usl-base/2.5.0.SNAPSHOT: missing requirement [usl-base/2.5.0.SNAPSHOT] osgi.identity; osgi.identity=hibernate-validator-osgi-karaf-features; type=karaf.feature]]
```

As I'm used to now, the last identity referenced here is the thing it can't find, unsurprisingly this new feature I'm referencing.

I then verified that the following file exists:

```
~/.m2/repository/org/hibernate/hibernate-validator-osgi-karaf-features/5.4.1.Final/hibernate-validator-osgi-karaf-features-5.4.1.Final-features.xml
```

However, I found it curious that it begins with the following content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<features xmlns="http://karaf.apache.org/xmlns/features/v1.4.0"
    name="hibernate-validator-osgi-features"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://karaf.apache.org/xmlns/features/v1.4.0">
```

The “name” property of the top-level features element is “hibernate-validator-osgi-features”, not “hibernate-validator-osgi-karaf-features”.  Is that a problem?

**Update**:

I now understand that my features file has to reference a feature named "hibernate-validator", which is defined in that "hibernate-validator-osgi-karaf-features" artifact.  That appears to have resolved my Karaf package resolution problems.  However, that simply puts me back to my original problem of:

```
Unable to create a Configuration, because no Bean Validation provider could be found. Add a provider like Hibernate Validator (RI) to your classpath.
```

I tried changing the "LogLevel" in my Pax Exam config from WARNING to DEBUG.  This gave me a lot more karaf debug output, but it didn't give me any significant info about why HV is not found in the classpath.

Is there some other debugging I can configure, or configuration in Pax Exam, that can help here?

Comment: As to your last update ("No BV provider found"), did you either specify a custom `ValidationProviderResolver` which explicitly returns Hibernate Validator _or_ bootstrap Bean Validation by calling `byProvider( HibernateValidator.class )`? One of the two is needed as the code in the API JAR won't find the service provider in the RI JAR without it.

Comment: Did you ever sort this out? Also trying to shoehorn Hiberation validation into Karaf and hitting the same issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just take a look at our Karaf integration tests for the 5.4 branch:

https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-validator/tree/5.4/osgi/integrationtest

We also use Pax Exam. You should be able to make it work if you follow what we did.

BTW, I see you mention the annotation processor in your dependency for the 2nd time, it's not something you need at runtime. The annotation processor is used to check that the annotations you used make sense at compile time. You should only enable it when you build your project.

See the Maven example here: https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/validator/reference/en-US/html_single/#validator-annotationprocessor-commandline .

Comment: Thanks for replying, but i'm getting a different unexpected error when I add this. I'll update the main post with more details.

Answer (score 0):

This solved it for me:

https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_jboss_fuse/6.2/html/apache_cxf_development_guide/Validation#Validation-Intro-Resolver

Read from "Configuring the validation provider explicitly in OSGi"

The problem is that in OSGI CXF has trouble to find the provider automatically so you have to resolve manually by passing the hibernate validator as a constructor argument to the CXF Bean Validation Provider.

Hope this helps :)